# use JS variable inside jQuery .css() call to specify the name of CSS property

Tags: javascript

Trying to do some logic to ensure tooltips show within the viewable area.  How can I use my `flot_position` variable within my `.css()` shown below?

```
//tooltip stuff
function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {

    var window_width = $( window ).width();
    if( x > (window_width - 60) )
    {
        var flot_position = 'right';
    }
    else
    {
        var flot_position = 'left';
    }


    $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
            position: 'absolute',
            display: 'none',
            top: y + 5,
            flot_position: x + 15, // This doesn't set 'left' or 'right' to x+15
            border: '1px solid #333',
            padding: '4px',
            color: '#fff',
            'border-radius': '3px',
            'background-color': '#333',
            opacity: 0.80
        }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
}
```

Comment: @DavidThomas: It won't work as written, it adds a property called `flot_position`, not a property called `left` or `right`. The error would be that the tooltip doesn't end up in the right place.

Comment: @DavidThomas to add on T.J's comment, it will result in invalid css..

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: for some reason that surprises me, though having read your answer I think it's something I already had trouble with, once. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Call the `css(propertyName, propertyValue)` version as shown by Amit in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24721488/157247).

   ```
   $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
       position: 'absolute',
       display: 'none',
       top: y + 5,
       border: '1px solid #333',
       padding: '4px',
       color: '#fff',
       'border-radius': '3px',
       'background-color': '#333',
       opacity: 0.80
   }).css(flot_position, x + 15)
   .appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
   ```
2. Create the options object in advance, then add to it, and use it:

   ```
   var cssOptions = {
       position: 'absolute',
       display: 'none',
       top: y + 5,
       border: '1px solid #333',
       padding: '4px',
       color: '#fff',
       'border-radius': '3px',
       'background-color': '#333',
       opacity: 0.80
   };
   cssOptions[flot_position] = x + 15;
   $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css(cssOptions).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
   ```

The second option works because although you can't use a variable name on the left-hand side of the property initializer in an object initializer, you *can* use a variable name with brackets notation after the initializer to add the property. In JavaScript you can access (get/set) a property on an object with dotted notation and a literal property name (`obj.foo`), and with bracketed notation and a *string* property name (`obj["foo"]`). In the bracketed notation, the string can be the result of any expression, including a variable lookup.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'none',
    top: y + 5,
    border: '1px solid #333',
    padding: '4px',
    color: '#fff',
    'border-radius': '3px',
    'background-color': '#333',
    opacity: 0.80
}).css(flot_position, x + 15) // use chaining and use .css(key,value) overload
.appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
```